# print last executed query in controller cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

suppose i have a query in cakephp 3

```
$post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Postmeta']
    ]);
```

I want to print it like plain mysql query for example

```
SELECT * FROM posts....
```

can anyone please explain this how can i achieve this. Please answer it only in cakephp 3 environment. Is it possible to print it in controller as normal mysql query ? please do not mention queries.log file solution. beacause it is time  taking to open file and see the query after every executed query in queries.log file in that is look in cakephp style
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last run query in CakePHP 3.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291033/how-to-get-last-run-query-in-cakephp-3-2)

Comment: @bill I saw that solution but queries.log file show query in cakephp style. I want to print it like plain mysql query like SELECT *  FROM posts. and also i want to see print it on my controller file. Is it possible ?

Comment: There are couple of ways to print sql just before it get execution. I think you need it after execution right ?

Comment: yes @ManoharKhadka

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, We need to write two lines after query code as follows

```
$post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
   'contain' => ['Postmeta']
]);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(debug($post));die;
```

It will show all result along with sql query syntax.

Here we are using [debug](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table) for show result along with sql query.

Answer (score -2):

**Query:**

```
$post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Postmeta']
]);
```

For Print/Get SQL Statement of above query you can use [debug()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table) function as follow in controller:

```
$post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Postmeta']
]);
debug($post);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just write:

```
die(print_r($post));
```