# How can i get executed query in cakephp3 in case of save & delete. My requirement is to save query in database

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Please help me to solve below queries on cakephp3

**1.** How can i get executed query in cakephp3 in case of save & delete. My requirement is to save query in database.
**2.** Is it possible to get the query inside any of callback function like eg. BeforeSave, AfterSave, AfterSaveCommit, BeforeDelete .. etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last run query in CakePHP 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291033/how-to-get-last-run-query-in-cakephp-3-2)

Comment: no, my question is different. I need last executed query inside callback function so that i can store query on database or log query for some table not for all.